# Finding category for words

Tags: nlp

I want to find a bigger category for words. For example

blue --> color

cat --> animal

happiness --> emotion

What is the easiest way to get this?

I checked the Wordnet demo : http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?c=8&sub=Change&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&i=-1&h=0000000000000000&s=blue

But I don't exactly know which field in Wordnet can help me to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a clear way of getting what you need unless you can define it more concretely. For example:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> blue = wn.synsets('blue')[0]
>>> cat = wn.synsets('cat')[0]
>>> blue.definition()
u'blue color or pigment; resembling the color of the clear sky in the daytime'
>>> cat.definition()
u'feline mammal usually having thick soft fur and no ability to roar: domestic cats; wildcats'
```

Sometimes, you get lucky and go up one or two level of the hypernyms:

```
>>> blue.hypernyms()
[Synset('chromatic_color.n.01')]
>>> blue.hypernyms()[0].hypernyms()
[Synset('color.n.01')]
```

Sometimes you have to go many level up the hypernyms to get to what you want.

```
>>> cat.hypernyms()
[Synset('feline.n.01')]
>>> cat.hypernyms()[0].hypernyms()
[Synset('carnivore.n.01')]
>>> cat.hypernyms()[0].hypernyms()[0].hypernyms()
[Synset('placental.n.01')]
>>> cat.hypernyms()[0].hypernyms()[0].hypernyms()[0].hypernyms()
[Synset('mammal.n.01')]
>>> cat.hypernyms()[0].hypernyms()[0].hypernyms()[0].hypernyms()[0].hypernyms()
[Synset('vertebrate.n.01')]
>>> cat.hypernyms()[0].hypernyms()[0].hypernyms()[0].hypernyms()[0].hypernyms()[0].hypernyms()
[Synset('chordate.n.01')]
>>> cat.hypernyms()[0].hypernyms()[0].hypernyms()[0].hypernyms()[0].hypernyms()[0].hypernyms()[0].hypernyms()
[Synset('animal.n.01')]
```

And getting to the top most hypernym level makes not much sense:

```
>>> blue.root_hypernyms()
[Synset('entity.n.01')]
>>> cat.root_hypernyms()
[Synset('entity.n.01')]
```

Sometimes there is just no hypernym for you to go to:

```
>>> happy = wn.synsets('happy')[0]
>>> happy.definition()
u'enjoying or showing or marked by joy or pleasure'
>>> happy.hypernyms()
[]
>>> happy.root_hypernyms()
[Synset('happy.a.01')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Got it! 
At the page: 
http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&r=1&s=blue&i=2&h=1000000000000000000#c

I just need to click on "S" and then "directed hypernym".

Comment: Super helpful. Been looking for this word hypernym for a while now. Also, a synonym I found was "superordinate".